# c# interop excel: Is there a way to display deleted duplicated records?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

This question is about `RemoveDuplicates` method in interop excel.

I wanted to display the `unique records count` and deleted `duplicate records count`, something like that of excel:

[image: Excel message box after Remove Duplicate]

***I do realize that I can do this through simple calculations*** and I also tried this, which worked perfect for me. So here is my **working code**:

```
int actualRowCnt = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
long n = worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
object cols = new object[]{1, 2};
range.Select();
range.Activate();
range.RemoveDuplicates(cols, Excel.XlYesNoGuess.xlYes);
//after removing duplicates:
int uniqueRowCnt = worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
// and finally:
int duplicateCntRemoved = actualRowCnt - uniqueRowCnt;
```

**What I want**: Is there any `in-built method` to do so? Unfortunately I didn't find any such method! So I had to post this. Any help appreciated. Thank you.